# Get the column of a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

Using R, my data set `L` is a list of lists. My `print(L)` produces the following output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.8198689

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.8166747


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.5798426

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.5753511


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0.4713508

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 0.4698621
```

And I want to get a vector of the second column. However `unlist(L[[2]])` gives me the second row (not the second column) and `L[,2]` gives me the error `Error in L[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions`. I tried also `L$'2`' and didn't work.

How can I get the vector of the second column of this data set in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use sapply (or use lapply if you want it as a list).  No packages are used.

```
sapply(L, `[[`, 2)
## [1] 0.8166747 0.5753511 0.4698621
```

**2)** Using purrr we have:

```
library(purrr)

transpose(L)[[2]]
## [[1]]
## [1] 0.8166747
##  
## [[2]]
## [1] 0.5753511
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 0.4698621
```

**3)** If we know that L is regularly shaped we could convert it to a matrix and then take the second column.

```
matrix(unlist(L), length(L), byrow = TRUE)[, 2]
## [1] 0.8166747 0.5753511 0.4698621
```

or as a list

```
do.call("rbind", L)[, 2]
```

**4)** The second column here is the last item in each "row" and if that is what you want as it would work even if the list is ragged then try this

```
mapply('[[', L, lengths(L))
## [1] 0.8166747 0.5753511 0.4698621
```

or as a list

```
Map('[[', L, lengths(L))
```

### Note

```
# input in reproducible form
L <- list(
  list(0.8198689, 0.8166747),
  list(0.5798426, 0.5753511),
  list(0.4713508, 0.4698621))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this using `purrr` is just to use `map()`, which returns a list.

```r
library(purrr)

map(L, 2)
```

If you want a (numeric) vector, use `map_dbl()`.

```r
map_dbl(L, 2)
# [1] 0.8166747 0.5753511 0.4698621
```